# Using htaccess to remove sub-directories from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-url

My CodeIgniter project is placed inside sub-folders and I want to hide those two sub-folders with `.htaccess`.

Everything is working fine but my current URL looks like this:

```
example.com/folder1/folder2/ci_project/class/function/$id
```

I want this to be:

```
example.com/class/function/$id
```

Now, I am using this simple `.htaccess` code in order to remove the `index.php` from URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any Ideas?

when i use the following code in htaccess file inside folder1/folder2/ci_project, it does hide the sub directories but i get the error "Object not found"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/folder2/ci_project/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/ci_project/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: could you post the .htaccess that you are currently using?

Comment: Place the index.php file outside in root and set the application and system path in it to the subfolder.

Comment: Any feedback would be appreciated. Could you give the current answer a try?

Answer (score 0):

Move your current `.htaccess` file from your `ci_project/` to the root of domain, and replace these code inside it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond $1 !^(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/ci_project/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In this case, you should place your public files in a folder like `public` at the root of the domain.

You should add other folders (like `public`) to `RewriteCond` if you don’t want them to be treated by `RewriteRule`.

If multiple application are exist in the same domain, you might want to consider this option:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/ci_project/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```